# Showing that limit exists iff left and right limits are equal

Tags: real-analysis, calculus, limits

Theorem of interest:

> The limit at an interior point of the domain of a function exists if
> and only if the left-hand limit and the right-hand limit exist and are
> equal to each other.

I'm using the $ \epsilon$-$\delta $ definition of limits and will be proving by contradiction.

Let $f$ be a function of $x$ defined within an open interval around $x_0$ (where $x_0$ need not be defined). Let the limit of $f$ as $x$ approaches $x_0$ be $L$. Let $f$ be:
$$
  f(x) = \cases{        x_0 +a       & $x > x_0$ \cr
                 x_0 -a & $x<x_0$
}
$$
where $a>0 , a \in\Re $.

Suppose the limit $L$ does exist. Let $\epsilon = \frac{1}{2}$ (an arbitrary small number) and $\delta = \delta_{\epsilon}>0$.
Since $L$ exists then it must be that for all $x \in \left( x_0-\delta, x_0+\delta\right)$, we have $\left| f(x) - L\right|<\epsilon = \frac{1}{2}$. However, at $x=x_0+\frac{\delta}{2}$ and $x=x_0-\frac{\delta}{2}$ (random values within given domain of f),
$$
\begin{align}
\left| f\left(x_0 + \frac{\delta}{2}\right) - f\left(x_0+\frac{\delta}{2} \right) \right| & = (x_0+a) - (x_0-a) \cr
\left| f\left(x_0 + \frac{\delta}{2}\right) - L + L - f\left(x_0+\frac{\delta}{2} \right) \right| & = 2a \cr
\left| f\left( x_0 + \frac{\delta}{2} \right) -L \right| + \left| -\left( f\left( x_0 -\frac{\delta}{2}\right)-L \right) \right| &\geq 2a \cr
\frac{1}{2} + \frac{1}{2} &\geq 2a \cr
1 &\ngeq 2a \text{   (contradiction since $a>0$)}
\end{align}
$$
Hence, we can see that because of the fact that the limit L does not exist, the arithmetic between the functions resulted in a contradiction. However, I'm not sure if the said proof is rigorous (not sure what that means). I picked $\epsilon=\frac{1}{2}$ because in limits we are playing on the notion of $x$ approaching a certain value, hence epsilon is logically small. If epsilon is large enough there wouldn't be (or at least, inconclusive) a contradiction as we see above.

So, did I miss anything?

Comment: I only skimmed, and aren't able to follow the last few lines of the chunk of inequalities. Also, are you sure you've derived a proof by contradiction (proving $P\iff Q$ by contradiction might involve first assuming `(P or Q) and (not P or not Q)`, then deriving some absurdity)?

Comment: At the line where the inequalities are involved, By spiting the absolute function we see that the equation is no longer equals, by rather an inequality. As for the proof by contradiction, I assumed that if i can show something in the logic breaking down, that would be the contradiction. I'm not too sure how to do it properly, any suggestion on how I can improve on that? At this point I'm not saying that my solution is correct at all. Thanks in advance! @RyanG

Comment: I was referring to the last two lines: you have derived (from the starting assumption) that $a$ is at most half; then you suddenly claim that $a$ is *not* at most half, and also that a is positive, and also that there is a contradiction. It in unclear if the last line is still part of the derivation of if it is a known result that is cited to exhibit a contradiction, and where/what the contradiction here even is. As for suggestion(s), if nobody posts an Answer, I may post something later. -)

Comment: I'm not sure if I'm following your train of thought, how did you get the impression that a is at most half? @RyanG
The posts you've made are very helpful, though it'll be great if you could write one up for this proof too :)

Comment: Isn’t that what your second line from the last says?

Comment: ah i see... though my intention was actually to show that "there is no way 1 is greater than 2a" i see now that the will be a problem when it is represented as "a is at most half". I think the problem here is that a is undefined, however, for some values of a the assumption holds true.

Comment: @RyanG (2) In the final line, the intention was that since $ \left| f\left( x_0 + \frac{\delta}{2} \right) -L \right| + \left| -\left( f\left( x_0 -\frac{\delta}{2}\right)-L \right) \right| \geq \left| f\left(x_0 + \frac{\delta}{2}\right) - L + L - f\left(x_0+\frac{\delta}{2} \right) \right| = 2a $ and thus because of the assumption that the limit exists 2a must be smaller than half, which now i know is not true because a is undefined. (4) No it is not required that I use proof by contradiction, I'll try to think of an alternative to my question, else i'll just delete it thank you.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Theorem of interest:

> The limit at an interior point of the domain of a function exists if
> and only if the left-hand limit and the right-hand limit exist and are
> equal to each other.

Here's a proof, first in the forward, then in the reverse, direction:

1. Suppose that an accumulation point $c$ of the domain of a function $f$ with
   domain $D$ have limit $l,$ i.e.,
   $$\forall\varepsilon{>}0\;\exists\delta{>}0\;\forall x{\in}
   D\,\Big(0{<}|x-c|{<}\delta\implies|f(x)-l|{<}\varepsilon\Big).$$ Then
   $$\forall\varepsilon{>}0\;\exists\delta{>}0\;\forall x{\in}
   D\,\Big(0{<}x-c{<}\delta\:\text{ or
   }\:0{<}c-x{<}\delta\implies|f(x)-l|{<}\varepsilon\Big);\\
   \forall\varepsilon{>}0\;\exists\delta{>}0\;\forall x{\in}
   D\,\Big(c{<}x{<}c+\delta\:\text{ or
   }\:c-\delta{<}x{<}c\implies|f(x)-l|{<}\varepsilon\Big);\\
   \forall\varepsilon{>}0\;\exists\delta{>}0\;\forall x{\in}
   D\,\Big(\big(c{<}x{<}c+\delta\implies|f(x)-l|{<}\varepsilon\big)\\\text{ and
   }\big(c-\delta{<}x{<}c\implies|f(x)-l|{<}\varepsilon\big)\Big);\\
   \forall\varepsilon{>}0\;\exists\delta{>}0\;\forall x{\in}
   D\,\Big(c{<}x{<}c+\delta\implies|f(x)-l|{<}\varepsilon\Big)\\\text{ and
   }\,\forall\varepsilon{>}0\;\exists\delta{>}0\;\forall x{\in}
   D\,\Big(c-\delta{<}x{<}c\implies|f(x)-l|{<}\varepsilon\Big);$$ so, $f$ has
   equal left- and right- limits at $c.$
2. Suppose that an accumulation point $c$ of the domain of a function $f$ with
   domain $D$ have left- and right- limits $l,$ i.e.,
   $$\forall\varepsilon{>}0\;\exists\delta{>}0\;\forall x{\in}
   D\,\Big(c{<}x{<}c+\delta\implies|f(x)-l|{<}\varepsilon\Big)\\\text{ and
   }\,\forall\varepsilon{>}0\;\exists\delta{>}0\;\forall x{\in}
   D\,\Big(c-\delta{<}x{<}c\implies|f(x)-l|{<}\varepsilon\Big).$$ Then (choosing
   $\delta_3=\min(\delta_1,\delta_2)$),
   $$\forall\varepsilon{>}0\;\exists\delta_1{>}0\;\exists\delta_2{>}0\;\forall
   x{\in}
   D\,\Big(\big(c{<}x{<}c+\delta_1\implies|f(x)-l|{<}\varepsilon\big)\\\text{ and
   }\big(c-\delta_2{<}x{<}c\implies|f(x)-l|{<}\varepsilon\big)\Big);\\
   \forall\varepsilon{>}0\;\exists\delta_1{>}0\;\exists\delta_2{>}0\;\forall
   x{\in} D\,\Big(c{<}x{<}c+\delta_1 \:\text{ or
   }\: c-\delta_2{<}x{<}c \implies|f(x)-l|{<}\varepsilon\Big);\\
   \forall\varepsilon{>}0\;\exists\delta_3{>}0\;\forall x{\in}
   D\,\Big(0{<}|x-c|{<}\delta_3\implies|f(x)-l|{<}\varepsilon\Big);$$ so, $f$
   has a limit at $c.$

Comment: Wow i think I'm decades away from writing like that... thank you for your patience and time!

Comment: Aha! Elegant and precise proof. According to me, the “main idea” for this proof is $p \vee q \Rightarrow r $ iff $ p \Rightarrow r \wedge q \Rightarrow r$. Is there formal way to prove this logic statement.I have little to no knowledge of logic.

Comment: My Question 3, I particularly asked for proof using limit of sequence definition.

Comment: $p=c\lt x \lt c+ \delta$, $q=c - \delta \lt x \lt c$ and $r=|f(x)-l| \lt \epsilon$.

Comment: In going from $$\forall\varepsilon{>}0\,\exists\delta{>}0\,\forall x{\in}
D\,\Big(\big(c{<}x{<}c+\delta\implies|f(x)-l|{<}\varepsilon\big) \text{ and
}\big(c-\delta{<}x{<}c\implies|f(x)-l|{<}\varepsilon\big)\Big)$$ to $$\forall\varepsilon{>}0\,\exists\delta{>}0\,\forall x{\in}
D\,\Big(c{<}x{<}c+\delta\implies|f(x)-l|{<}\varepsilon\Big) \text{ and
}\forall\varepsilon{>}0\,\exists\delta{>}0\,\forall x{\in}
D\,\Big(c-\delta{<}x{<}c\implies|f(x)-l|{<}\varepsilon\Big),$$ what rule is this?

Comment: It seems like you are distributing the quantifiers, however, when distributing an existential quantifier over a conjunction we only have an implication, right?

Comment: @sunny Referring to the two lines you quoted as A and B, then while A and B are not *equivalent*, A indeed *implies* B.