# Neighborhood of $x$, for $\lim_{x \to a} \sqrt{x}$

Tags: calculus, limits

I know that for $\lim\limits_{x \to a} \sqrt{x} = \sqrt{a}$.

From the definition of the limit, it implies that if $\lim\limits_{x \to a} f(x)=L\ \text{then} \ \forall \varepsilon \gt 0 \ \exists \delta \gt 0 |\  0\lt |x-a|\lt\delta \implies |f(x)-L|\lt \varepsilon$.

If I take $a=2$, $\lim\limits_{x \to 2} \sqrt{x} = \sqrt{2}$, this would mean I could take a neighborhood of at the max only 2 for x because if I take a neighborhood of more than 2 from the left the neighborhood would enter negative $x$-axis.

So there is a strict restriction on the $\delta$ that I'm considering which would imply a further caveat on values of $\varepsilon$ which implies the neighborhood here does not hold $\forall \varepsilon$.

So there should be an additional statement missing in the definition, or I'm missing something in the interpretation.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is a fuller definition of $$\lim\limits_{x \to a} f(x)=L,$$ where the domain $D$ of $f$ is a superset of a punctured neighbourhood<sup>҂</sup> of $a:$ $$\forall\varepsilon{>}0\;\exists\delta{>}0\;\color{red}{\forall x{\in} D}\,\bigg(0<|x-a|<\delta\implies|f(x)-L|<\varepsilon\bigg).$$

  <sup>҂</sup> For $\lim\limits_{x \to a} f(x)$ to exist, $f$ must be defined on a punctured neighbourhood of $a$—though not necessarily at $a$ itself.

Comment: Can you explain how the addition of $\forall x \in D$ changes the interpretation?

Comment: @Orpheus Since our $f$ has domain $\mathbb R^+_0,$ the additional quantification forbids us from entering the negative $x$-axis, the very issue that was bothering you. It is not $\delta$ per se / directly that is being restricted, but actually $x.$ To be clear, we aren't actually expanding the definition, just making explicit the portion of it that's frequently left implicit. Related: [limit exists iff left limit = right limit](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/4277300/21813)

Comment: Thanks a lot, @Ryan G!...I never thought of it like that

Comment: I'm sorry @Ryan G...I clicked on the upward arrow...and now when you bought it up I realized that it didn't imply I accepted the answer....your answer perfectly resolved my confusion...thanks once again

Comment: @Orpheus A good follow-up question to ponder is: why is $\forall x{\in}D$ inserted as above instead of before the other two quantifiers

Comment: wouldn't that supersede the condition on $\epsilon$?

Comment: @Orpheus Exactly: with mixed quantifiers, the order matters, and I was merely suggesting to practise thinking about the difference between the two versions

Comment: thanks a lot @Ryan G

Answer (score 1):

There is something missing in the definition, yes. Let $D_f$ be the domian of $f$. Then the definition of $\lim_{x\to a}f(x)=L$ is$$(\forall\varepsilon>0)(\exists\delta>0):0<|x-a|<\delta\color{red}{\wedge x\in D_f}\implies\bigl|f(x)-L\bigr|<\varepsilon.$$

Answer (score 1):

I think that you might perhaps be misjudging your quantifiers. When you pick an arbitrary $\epsilon$, you then simply have to show that there exist a single $\delta$ satisfying your definition. In your example you seem to be choosing your $\delta$ first and claiming that an $\epsilon$ does not exist for that value. This is erroneous.

You are correct in that there are restrictions on $\delta$ but that doesn't matter since you simply have to pick a single value once $\epsilon$ has been fixed.

Comment: the definition states any $\varepsilon$....I pick $\varepsilon =4$ for $x \to 2$