# Rudin’s PMA: Theorem 4.25

Tags: real-analysis, proof-writing

Let $f$ be real function defined on (a,b). Let $p \in [a,b)$. We write $$f(p+)= \lim_{x\to p+}f(x)=q$$ if $\lim_{n\to \infty}f(p_n)=q$, for every sequence {$p_n$} in $(p,b)$ s.t $p_n \to p$. This is the definition of right hand limit of $f$ at p.

**Question(1):** How do I go from this limit of sequence definition to $\epsilon-\delta$ definition. **My attempt:** Applying theorem 4.2, without thinking too much, I get this $\lim_{x\to p}f(x)=q$. Which I known, that’s not correct.

**Question(2):** $\epsilon-\delta$ definition from Wikipedia. It is,$$\forall\varepsilon > 0,\exists \delta >0 s.t \forall x \in (a,b), 0 < x - a < \delta \Rightarrow |f(x) - L|<\varepsilon$$ just by looking at this definition of RHL, it is not clear to write expression like in this form $\lim_{x\to ?}f(x)=q$. Assume for a moment, that we manage to write expression in the above form. Now, can we reach to the limit of sequence definition given in theorem 4.25, for RHL?

**Question(3):** i can’t prove the following claim $$\lim_{x\to p}f(x)=q exist \iff f(p+)=f(p-)=q$$ using limit of sequence definition. **Attempt** There is nothing. After writing all definitions, there is zero progress.

**Providing more context:** I think $\epsilon-\delta$ definition is easier to apply than limit of sequence definition, in most problems. That is just my opinion. When I see a problem about RHL & LHL, I have to look for graphs. I can’t prove it by definition of one sided limit.

**Warning:** My question generally contains error and/or misunderstanding of concept. If you find something wrong then mention it on comment.

Edit: In short, I am asking a proof for two equivalent definition of RHL.

Comment: Something missed in line 3 ?: If $\lim_{n\to\infty}f(p_n)=q$,  for every sequence ...  "then ..."?

Comment: I'm sorry. What are you referring to?

Comment: @user In Line $3 'If' should be changed to 'if'.

Comment: @KaviRamaMurthy: Ah ha, make sense!

Comment: Yeah. I have edited it.

Comment: I recently answered your Question 3 [right here](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/4277300/21813).

Comment: Thank you for link. Now, I can atleast prove that, using epsilon delta definition.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I was facing the same problem as you mentioned in Question (3) the last two days. I tried to tackle the if part by using contradiction, similar to the proof of the if part of Theorem 4.2. [Here is the screenshot; hope it is not blured](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Pdxkj.png). To clarify, the $B(x,\delta) := \{t\in (a,b)\colon |x - t| < \delta\}$ is the open ball centered at $x$.

Comment: Please do not use pictures for critical portions of your post. Pictures may not be legible, cannot be searched and are not view-able to some, such as those who use screen readers. For some basic information about writing mathematics at this site see [basic help on mathjax notation](/help/notation) and [mathjax tutorial and quick reference](//math.meta.stackexchange.com/q/5020).

Comment: Hey welcome to SE. I think your solution is correct and precise. Thank you so much for the answer. I really appreciate your effort.