# Rudin’s PMA: Theorem 6.20

Tags: real-analysis, integration, proof-writing, solution-verification

> Let $f \in \Re$ on $[a,b]$. For $  a \leq x \leq b$, put: $F(x)  = \int_a^x f(t)dt$, Then $F$ is continuous on $[a,b]$; furthermore, if $f$ is continuous at a point $x_0$  of $[a,b]$, then $F$ is differentiable at $x_o$ and $F'(x_0) = f(x_0)$.

> **Proof:** Suppose $f$ is continuous at $x_0$. Given $\epsilon > 0 $ choose $\delta > 0$ such that:$\vert f(t)- f(x_o) \vert < \epsilon $, if $\vert t- x_0 \vert < \delta$, and  $a \leq t \leq b $.Hence, if $x_0 - \delta < s \leq x_0 \leq t < x_0 + \delta$ with  $a\ \leq s < t \leq b$. we have by theorem 6.12(d),$\left| \frac{F(t) - F(s)}{t-s} - f(x_0) \right| = \left| \frac{1}{t-s} \int_s^t [f(u) - f(x_0)]du \right| < \epsilon$. It follows that $F'(x_0) = f(x_0)$

**Question(1)** Claim: $\left| \frac{F(t) - F(s)}{t-s} - f(x_0) \right| = \left| \frac{1}{t-s} \int_s^t [f(u) - f(x_0)]du \right| < \epsilon$. **Proof:** The first equality is pretty clear from theorem 6.12(d). Since $f \in \mathscr{R}$ on $[a,b]$ and $s,t \in [a,b]$, $f \in \mathscr{R}$ on $[s,t]$. $f(x_0) \in \mathscr{R}$ on $[s,t]$, because $f(x_0)$ is constant. So $f-f(x_0) \in \mathscr{R}$ on $[s,t]$,$\int_{s}^t [f(u)-f(x_0)] du \in \Bbb{R}$. By theorem 1.33(c), $\left| \frac{1}{t-s} \int_s^t [f(u) - f(x_0)]du \right| = \frac{1}{t-s} | \int_s^t [f(u) - f(x_0)]du |$. By theorem 6.13(b), $\frac{1}{t-s} | \int_s^t [f(u) - f(x_0)]du | \leq \frac{1}{t-s} \int_s^t |f(u) - f(x_0)|du$. Since $u \in [s,t] \subset (x_0-\delta, x_0+\delta)$, we have by continuity of $f$ at $x_0$, $|f(u) - f(x_0)| \lt \epsilon$. By theorem 6.12(b), $\frac{1}{t-s} \int_s^t |f(u) - f(x_0)|du \lt \frac{1}{t-s} \int_s^t \epsilon du = \frac{1}{t-s} \epsilon \int_s^t du = \epsilon$. Thus, $\left| \frac{F(t) - F(s)}{t-s} - f(x_0) \right| \lt \epsilon$. **Is this proof correct?**

**Question(2)** Though we have proved stronger result in relatively short length. It is not clear(at least to me) that $F^{\prime}(x_0)=\lim_{x \to x_0} \frac{F(x)-F(x_0)} {x-x_0}=f(x_0)$. By definition 4.25, which is $\lim_{x\to p}f(x)=q$ exist $\iff f(p+)=f(p-)=q$. For proof of this claim you can check [Theorem 4.25 of Baby Rudin](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/4282578/861687) one of my post. There are two ways(limit of sequence, https://math.stackexchange.com/a/4288555/861687 and $\epsilon - \delta$ definition, https://math.stackexchange.com/a/4277300/861687 ) to proof the above claim. To show $F^{\prime}(x_0+)=\lim_{x \to x_0^{+}} \frac{F(x)-F(x_0)} {x-x_0}=f(x_0)$. For $\epsilon \gt 0$, take same $\delta$ as we took for continuity of $f$ at $x_0$ so that $x_0 \lt t \lt x_0 + \delta \Rightarrow \left| \frac{F(t) - F(x_0)}{t-x_0} - f(x_0) \right| \lt \epsilon$. Thus, $F(x_0+)=f(x_0)$. This is the definition of one sided limit(https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/One-sided_limit#Formal_definition). Yeah, in this case, we put $s=x_0$. The proof for $F(x_0-)=f(x_0)$ is very similar to $F(x_0+)=f(x_0)$. In that case, we take $t=x_0$. So $x_0 - \delta \lt s \lt x_0 \Rightarrow \left| \frac{F(s) - F(x_0)}{s-x_0} - f(x_0) \right| \lt \epsilon$. **Is this proof correct?**

Comment: The first looks fine. I'm not sure what the issue is with the second - is it the issue of when $x>x_0$?

Comment: @copper.hat What do you mean?

Comment: I don't know what you are trying to so in the second part that has not been done in the first.

Comment: @copper.hat ohhhh..... okay. I understand what you’re trying to ask. The claim I proved in first part, don’t “explicitly” show $F^\prime (x_0) = f(x_0)$. In other word, it is not in it’s standard form/notation. So I tryed to prove(rigorously) $F^\prime (x_0) = f(x_0)$, using the claim of first part.

Comment: By the way I got +100 reputation for absolutely nothing. Can you say why it happened?

Comment: No idea, did you sign up to another SE site? If you click on the Recent Achievements icon it usually indicated why.

Comment: I am not sure why you think the first proof is not explicit. It is perfectly fine.

Comment: @copper.hat I mean it is not in its standard notation, which is $\left| \frac{F(x) - F(x_0)}{x-x_0} - f(x_0) \right| \lt \epsilon$, instead of $ \left| \frac{F(t) - F(s)}{t-s} - f(x_0) \right| \lt \epsilon$.

Comment: @copper.hat It is showing we trust you on other site of this network.

Comment: A distinction without a difference :-).

Comment: The letter chosen does not matter (apart from clashs, of course!).

Comment: I am more inclined to the second personally. Yes, the other case can be shown very analogously. I don't know whether it's Rudin's intention to let the readers finish the other part or the ``implicit limit'' in your Question(1) is actually enough. UPDATE: I think the reason Rudin doing this is that he wants to include the boundary cases $i.e., s=x_{0}=a$ or $ s=x_{0}=b$. In these cases, we only have left/right limits. And for interior pts, we do need both.