# Does Left Hand Derivate and Right Hand Derivative being defined guarantee continuity?

Tags: real-analysis, calculus, limits, derivatives, continuity

Suppose at $x = a$, both the Left Hand Derivative and Right Hand Derivative of a function exists and **is defined**. In other words, both the limits $$\lim_{h \to 0^-} \frac{f(a+h)-f(a)}{h}$$ and $$\lim_{h \to 0^+} \frac{f(a+h)-f(a)}{h}$$ exist and are defined.

Does that guarantee that the function is continuous at $x = a$ (no matter the limits are equal or not)?

Comment: If by "defined" you mean being finite, then yes, it does.

Comment: Let's consider
$$f(x)=\begin{cases}x, &x>0\\
-x-1,& x<0
\end{cases}$$
what do you think about?

Comment: We have $$ \lim_{h\rightarrow 0^\pm} (f(a+h)-f(a))=\lim_{h\rightarrow 0^\pm}  \frac{f(a+h)-f(a)}{h} h = \lim_{h\rightarrow 0^\pm}  \frac{f(a+h)-f(a)}{h} \cdot \lim_{h\rightarrow 0^\pm} h =\lim_{h\rightarrow 0^\pm}  \frac{f(a+h)-f(a)}{h} \cdot 0=     0.$$

Comment: @zkutch I think that your function cannot be extended to $a=0$ in such a way that the onesided derivatives exist there.

Comment: @Severin Schraven. Why does it needed such a extension? Brought example satisfies the op requirements.

Comment: What does "exists and is defined"mean? Can something what is not defined exist?

Comment: @PaulFrost It means it's a real number (not infinity or undefined)

Comment: @SeverinSchraven Thank you very much. As Sourav said, would you mind making it an answer?

Comment: MangoPizza, and also @Severin Schraven, let me suggest you look at John M.H. Olmsted - Advanced calculus-Prentice Hall (1961), page 71.

Comment: @zkutch: In the question as posted, $f(a)$ appears as a term under the limit sign. So $f(a)$ has to be assigned a value in order for the post to make sense. But your example does not assign a value to $f(0)$, nor can a value even be assigned which makes both limits in the post exist as required.

Comment: @Lee Mosher. Left hand derivative is not same with derivative from left. Source above.

Comment: Well, it sounds like there is a disagreement somewhere in the definition of one-sided derivatives. But the OP is asking about particular expressions for the one-sided derivatives of $f(x)$ at $x=a$ (expressions that agree with all sources I know about, [here](https://proofwiki.org/wiki/Definition:One-Sided_Derivative) for example).

Comment: Let me say that I do agree that $\lim_{x \to a^-} f'(x) \ne \lim_{x \to a^+} f'(x)$ in your example, however $\lim_{x \to a^-} f'(x)$ is not generally equal to $\lim_{h \to 0^-} \frac{f(a+h)-f(a)}{h}$.

Comment: @zkutch I have posted a more natural language explanation of why it forces continuity. Your example is instructive though since if we don't force the function to be defined at $a$ it does provide a counter-example.

Comment: @Lee Mosher. The left-hand limit of derivative, which you mentioned, is third object generally different  from other two, in this situation. So we have 1. derivative from left, 2. left hand derivative, 3. left-hand limit of derivative. In mentioned book there is good analysis with counter examples.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

$\lim_{x\to a}f(x) =L$ iff $\lim _{x→a ^{−}} f (x) = L = \lim_{ x→a^{ +}} f (x)$
$\space$$($see [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/4273605/977780) $)$

---

If $\lim_{x\to a}f(x) =f(a) $ i.e $\lim_{h\to 0} f(a+h)=f(a)$ then $f$ is continuous at $a$.

---

Let $\lim_{h \to 0^-} \frac{f(a+h)-f(a)}{h}=l$

$\begin{align}\lim_{h \to 0^-} f(a+h) -f(a) &= \lim_{h \to 0^-}  \frac{f(a+h)-f(a)}{h}\cdot h\\&= \lim_{h \to 0^-}  \frac{f(a+h)-f(a)}{h} \cdot \lim_{h\to 0^-} h\\&=l\cdot 0\\&=0
 \end{align}$

Similarly  $\lim_{h \to 0^+} \frac{f(a+h)-f(a)}{h}=L$ implies

$\lim_{h \to 0^+} f(a+h) -f(a)=0$

---

$\lim_{h\to 0^+}f(a+h) =f(a) =\lim_{h\to 0^-}f(a+h) $

Hence $f$ is continuous at $a$.

Credit: [Severin Schraven](https://math.stackexchange.com/users/331816/severin-schraven)

Comment: Left hand derivative is not same with derivative from left. Source in my last comment.

Comment: @zkutch How would you define "left hand derivative " and "derivative from the left"? https://proofwiki.org/wiki/Definition:Left-Hand_Derivative#:~:text=The%20left%2Dhand%20derivative%20of,left%2Dhand%20differentiable%20at%20x.

Comment: Answer is in Olmsted's book mentioned above.

Comment: I like this answer :)

Answer (score 2):

Let $L^{+}$ denote the right hand limit. For $h > 0$ we have $f(a + h) = f(a) + hL^+ + o(h)$. Clearly $hL^+ + o(h) \to 0$ as $h \to 0$, so $f$ is right-continuous at $a$. The same argument shows that $f$ is left-continuous at $a$. Hence $f$ is continuous at $a$.

Answer (score 1):

For the derivative to exist at $a$ means there is an open set in the domain that contains $a$ where the derivative will be defined. Now since the function is continuous everywhere it's derivative is defined we have that the function is both left and right continuous at $a$. However since the open sets for the right and left hand derivative both contain $a$ it forces the left and right hand limits to be the same.